# ivy dependencies describing parallel execution

Tags: parallel-processing, ivy

I have a ivy based build, and my top level build script (simple enough) goes something like:

```
<target name="buildlist">
  <ivy:buildlist reference="build-path">
    <fileset dir="." includes="*/**/build.xml"/>
  </ivy:buildlist>
</target>


<target name="all" depends="buildlist" description="build, publish and report for all projects">
  <echo message="Calling 'all' on ${toString:build-path}."/>
  <subant target="all" buildpathref="build-path"/>
</target>
```

What would be REALLY cool is to be able to parallelize the build.  E.g, ivy knows dependencies and could indicate which subant calls could be run in parallel.  Anyone done something like this?

Comment: You're correct ivy understands the dependencies between modules and returns an ordered list. What is not returned is information on whether a module in the list is dependent on its preceding module, a condition that would prevent it from being run in parallel.

Comment: Yep, though ivy must know it.  Yes, the above build.xml snippet isn't going to cut it.. but perhaps something like ivy:buildlist that builds an acyclic graph instead of a list and we can parallelize from there.